# ImageView Clickable not functioning on Fragment - Android

Tags: android

I have an ImageView on a Fragment, which is clickable.. 
During testing I cannot get the clickable attribute to function.. 
So when I push the ImageView, nothing happens..

My code in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="202dp"
    android:layout_height="138dp"
        android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/pic_duckplate"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My code in the Fragment

```
public class Picture_Bowl_Fragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.picture_bowl, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Test", "Clicked Imageview");

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

The Activity Code.. 
This is an activity with more or less 15 fragments, who are loaded and changed in time to provide good UX, which is the goal of the project..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Top_Title_Fragment top_title_fragment = new Top_Title_Fragment();
    final Bereidingstijd_Text bereidingstijd_text = new Bereidingstijd_Text();
    final Waardering_Text waardering_text = new Waardering_Text();
    final Calorieen_Text calorieen_text = new Calorieen_Text();
    final Vaardigheid_Text vaardigheid_text = new Vaardigheid_Text();
    final Kruiden_Text kruiden_text = new Kruiden_Text();
    final Bereidingstijd_Value bereidingstijd_value = new Bereidingstijd_Value();
    final Waardering_Value waardering_value = new Waardering_Value();
    final Calorieen_Value calorieen_value = new Calorieen_Value();
    final Vaardigheid_Value vaardigheid_value = new Vaardigheid_Value();
    final Kruiden_Value kruiden_value = new Kruiden_Value();
    final Picture_Bowl_Fragment picture_bowl_fragment = new Picture_Bowl_Fragment();
    final Picture_DuckFull_Fragment picture_duckFull_fragment = new Picture_DuckFull_Fragment();
    final Picture_DuckPlate_Fragment picture_duckPlate_fragment = new Picture_DuckPlate_Fragment();
    final Bereiding_Button_Fragment bereiding_button_fragment = new Bereiding_Button_Fragment();
    final Ingredienten_Button_Fragment ingredienten_button_fragment = new Ingredienten_Button_Fragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_right, R.anim.slide_right)
                .add(R.id.container, bereidingstijd_text)
                .add(R.id.container, waardering_text)
                .add(R.id.container, calorieen_text)
                .add(R.id.container, vaardigheid_text)
                .add(R.id.container, kruiden_text)
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left, R.anim.slide_left)
                .add(R.id.container, bereidingstijd_value)
                .add(R.id.container, kruiden_value)
                .add(R.id.container, waardering_value)
                .add(R.id.container, calorieen_value)
                .add(R.id.container, vaardigheid_value)
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.slide_down)
                .add(R.id.container, bereiding_button_fragment)
                .add(R.id.container, ingredienten_button_fragment)
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_down_title, R.anim.slide_down_title)
                .add(R.id.container, top_title_fragment)
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.mid_pic_anim, R.anim.mid_pic_anim)
                .add(R.id.container, picture_bowl_fragment)
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.right_pic_anim, R.anim.slide_left)
                .add(R.id.container, picture_duckFull_fragment)
                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.left_pic_anim, R.anim.slide_right)
                .add(R.id.container, picture_duckPlate_fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .remove(bereidingstijd_text)
                        .remove(bereidingstijd_value)
                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.zoom_in_text, R.anim.zoom_in_text)
                        .add(R.id.container, bereidingstijd_text)
                        .add(R.id.container, bereidingstijd_value)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();

                final Handler handler1 = new Handler();

                handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .remove(bereidingstijd_text)
                                .remove(bereidingstijd_value)
                                .remove(waardering_text)
                                .remove(waardering_value)
                                .add(R.id.container, bereidingstijd_text)
                                .add(R.id.container, bereidingstijd_value)
                                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.zoom_in_text, R.anim.zoom_in_text)
                                .add(R.id.container, waardering_text)
                                .add(R.id.container, waardering_value)
                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                .commit();

                        final Handler handler2 = new Handler();

                        handler2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                        .remove(waardering_text)
                                        .remove(waardering_value)
                                        .remove(calorieen_text)
                                        .remove(calorieen_value)
                                        .add(R.id.container, waardering_text)
                                        .add(R.id.container, waardering_value)
                                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.zoom_in_text, R.anim.zoom_in_text)
                                        .add(R.id.container, calorieen_text)
                                        .add(R.id.container, calorieen_value)
                                        .addToBackStack(null)
                                        .commit();

                                final Handler handler3 = new Handler();

                                handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                                .remove(calorieen_text)
                                                .remove(calorieen_value)
                                                .remove(vaardigheid_text)
                                                .remove(vaardigheid_value)
                                                .add(R.id.container, calorieen_text)
                                                .add(R.id.container, calorieen_value)
                                                .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.zoom_in_text, R.anim.zoom_in_text)
                                                .add(R.id.container, vaardigheid_text)
                                                .add(R.id.container, vaardigheid_value)
                                                .addToBackStack(null)
                                                .commit();

                                        final Handler handler4 = new Handler();

                                        handler4.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                                        .remove(vaardigheid_text)
                                                        .remove(vaardigheid_value)
                                                        .remove(kruiden_text)
                                                        .remove(kruiden_value)
                                                        .add(R.id.container, vaardigheid_text)
                                                        .add(R.id.container, vaardigheid_value)
                                                        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.zoom_in_text, R.anim.zoom_in_text)
                                                        .add(R.id.container, kruiden_text)
                                                        .add(R.id.container, kruiden_value)
                                                        .addToBackStack(null)
                                                        .commit();
                                            }
                                        }, 3000L);
                                    }
                                }, 3000L);
                            }
                        }, 3000L);
                    }
                }, 3000L);
            }
        },3000L);
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what do you mean by "push the imageview, nothing happens?" Do you mean when you click on it? or something else? @Niels Vanwingh

Comment: when i click on it, sorry for the confusion..

Comment: Can you please disclose your activity code

Comment: Done in original post..

Comment: @NielsVanwingh when you click on image, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Go to fullscreen mode, but I have a Log.d method in the OnclickListener, and my log file shows nothing..

Comment: @NielsVanwingh Check my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Use android:src="@drawable/pic_duckplate instead of android:background="@drawable/pic_duckplate.

Comment: I tried this, and it does not change anything? For me this has nothing to do with the "clickable" attribute functioning, or does it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have tested this code, and Log.i does work. Make sure you have selected `Verbose` option to filter out logs. You can see that right beside log search option on top of the logs.

Also, I would suggest you to put `Toast` instead of `Log` inside image onClickListener.

You can do as follows, so you don't have to check logs. It will show message right on your screen.

```
  Toast.makeText(context, "ImageView clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Something like that. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I have tried to use toast.. but nothing is showing.. Be aware, I am using the onclicklistener in a Fragment, that could make a difference..

Comment: In fragment, it shouldn't matter. May be you can try putting onclicklistener in method called `OnViewCreated`. Override that method and move image click listener in that method. I tested piece of fragment code and it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()......
```

Use like this:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.container, your_fragment_object);
.........
.........
ft.commit();
```

Then your try your click listener. It will work.. Tested...

Comment: I would want to know as to why the answer was down voted ?